# how to loop through a multi dimensional associative array the correct way

Tags: php

i am at the point in my script where i want to insert data into my database after looping through an associative array.

the code works so far but since i am new to programming i wish to know if there is a more efficient alternative way of doing what i am doing, since i will be adding more elseif's when my array grows, and also the fact that i am querying my database after every iteration.

```
foreach($database as $key=>$value) {

foreach($value as $field => $cell){

    if ($field =='itemid') {
        echo "the item id is $cell";
        $col1 = $cell ;
    }
    elseif ($field =='title') {

        echo "the title is $cell";
        $col2 = $cell;
    }
    elseif ($field =='starttime') {

        echo "the start time is $cell";
        $col3 = $cell;
    }

}
$query = "INSERT INTO cordless_drill(itemid,title,starttime) VALUES ('$col1','$col2','$col3')";
mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

}
```

Comment: Maybe you should just map it and label it as literal as possible. So you can easily trace the `key:values`

Answer (score 0):

```
// here is a code snippet

// $db = new MyDbClass();

// $db->insert->('cordless_drill', $cell); // where $cell is holding key/value pairs 

public function insert($table, $obj) {
    return $this->query("INSERT INTO ".$table.$this->obj2KeyValue($obj));
}

private function obj2KeyValue($obj) {
    $i = count($obj);
    $k = ""; $v = "";       
    $init = false;
    $sql = " SET ";
    while (list($k, $v) = each($obj)) {
        if ($v != "") {
            $v = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($v);
            if ($init) $sql .= ", ";
            else $init = true;
            $sql .= $k.'="'.$v.'"';
        }
    }
    return $sql;

}


public function query($q) {
    if ($this->debug) {
        $logFile = "sql_query.log";
        $handle = fopen($logFile, "a+");
        $data = $q."\n";
        fwrite($handle, $data);
        fclose($handle);
    }       
    return $this->mysqli->query($q);
}
```